# Web.py not working with Apache using mod_wsgi

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi, wsgi, web.py

I am trying to get web.py to work with Apache. I'm following the instructions here: [Web.py + Apache with mod_wsgi](http://webpy.org/cookbook/mod_wsgi-apache)

This is what my httpd.conf looks like right now:

```
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so

WSGIScriptAlias /justcompare /var/www/justcompare/code.py

Alias /justcompare/static /var/www/justcompare/static
AddType text/html .py

<Directory /var/www/justcompare/>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

My code.py can be seen [here](http://pastebin.com/HP0NGiPW). The server returns a 404 not found when I try to visit [server's ip]/justcompare. Apache's error log is a little more enlightening. It says:

```
[Sun Nov 24 03:15:40 2013] [error] [client 192.168.1.100] mod_wsgi (pid=5489): Target WSGI script '/var/www/justcompare/code.py' does not contain WSGI application 'application'.
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A mod_wsgi compliant script should contain the name 'application' (the name is configurable through a mod_wsgi directive), which must be a WSGI compliant application object. If you do as the linked page says and remove **"if __name__ == '__main__"**  and rename 'app' to 'application', it should work.

Comment: It is mod_wsgi that requires the WSGI application entry point be called 'application'. It is not a requirement of the WSGI specification. There is a mod_wsgi directive which allows you to override the name looked for if necessary.